# How is possible to do topic authorization in Kafka?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

My system will have multiple customers, topics will be the customers, named with special codes.

Where is a way to implement Kafka topic authorization and to set them from code?

For example, from AdminClient is possible to create a topic, with some settings?

Comment: Unclear why this is tagged `.net`... Start here - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm trying to implement it in .NET. I read all their documentation, and some part are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `confluent-dotnet-kafka`'s AdminClient, you can create topics. Topic configs can be passed to `TopicSpecification` objects, but this does not include authentication details, as that is managed elsewhere, not exactly on a at-creation or per-topic basis. Refer [Github example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdminClient/Program.cs#L76)

No, you cannot use AdminClient to [specify ACLs, as this largely depends on the `authorizer.class.name` setup in the broker's `server.properties`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz). By default, the Zookeeper Authorizer uses [special `kafka-acls` script](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_cli).

This does not preclude writing/finding [your own `Authorizer`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/server/authorizer/Authorizer.java) that can be managed over some HTTP interface from `.NET`, however, or even using shell calls in `.NET` that wrap the `kafka-acls` script